# Mysql sum records which have tomorrow's date and after tomorrow etc

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my Mysql DB  I have a column called '**mydate**' with stored unix timestamps.

I need to get the SUM of all records, that:

- has the tomorrow's date (the time shouldn't be taken into consideration, only date)
- has today +2 days
- has today +3 days
  etc., but max. today +7 days

I did it this way (just an example for 2 upcoming days):

```
$sqld = "SELECT 
       sum(case when mydate= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS p1,
       sum(case when mydate= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS p2

       FROM mytable";
$rsld = $conn->Execute($sqld);
$x1=$rsld->fields['p1'];$x2=$rsld->fields['p2'];
```

But when I echo the `$x1` and `$x2`, there is only **0** for both. Definitely there are records for tomorrow and after tomorrow in my table.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It's easier to use WHERE to limit the search, and GROUP BY to group by the date. Is `mydate` a date column or a text column?

Comment: A timestamp includes a date and a time however you're using equality - you need to use ranges between date boundaries.

Comment: @aynber it is a text column actually

Comment: *I have a column called 'mydate' with stored unix timestamps.* Show CREATE TABLE script. PS. MySQL have no "unix timestamp" datatype.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of rows, or sum a particular field?

Comment: it is a text datatype which stores date as timestamps. And yes, I try to sum the rows with that date. I also posted an answer how did I solve it, I think it is easier as directly  work with dates in mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the datetimes as unix timestamps then you need to convert to datetime first and then remove the time portion. Try this

```
select 
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p1,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p2,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p3,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p4,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p5,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p6,
sum(case when date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) p7
from mytable 
where date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))>DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate))<=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found an easier solution.

I just define tomorrows and others date as variables:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$d1 = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date));
$d2 = strtotime('+2 day', strtotime($date));
```

and then just simply compare in Mysql:

```
sum(case when mydate = $d1 then 1 else 0 end) AS p1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're actually looking to count the number of rows instead of sum a particular field. You can use WHERE and GROUP BY to make it easier

```
SELECT mydate, count(id) as total 
FROM mytable 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This does turn it into multiple rows instead of a single row as your original query.